# Is there a colloquial equivalent for 提出する?

Tags: words

Is there a colloquial equivalent for 提出する?

For instance in a situation where an employee needs to transmit/give a file to the administration, or a student needs to transmit/give a homework to the teacher.

Is it possible to simply use あげる/くれる?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is 出{だ}す.

For examples：

- この書類を11月までに出さないといけない - This document must be handed in by November.
- 宿題を出し忘れた - Forgot to submit the homework.

As you may know, 宿題を出す can also mean *to give homework* from teacher's side. So technically the second sentence is ambiguous with *(the speaker as a teacher) forgot to assign homework*.